# Gridview row updating

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have to update my gridview row using the update link button but the gridview is not updating once the button is clicked.

here is my code in asp

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" GridLines="None" EmptyDatatext ="There are no records to display" OnRowEditing="EditViolation"
                OnRowCancelingEdit="CancelEdit">
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB"  />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Registry Number">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblRegNo" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("registry_no")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Vessel Name">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblVname" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ship_name")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Violation">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblViolation" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("violation")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                     <asp:Textbox ID="txtViolation" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("violation")%>'></asp:Textbox>
                               </EditItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date Violated">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblDateViolated" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("date_violated")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                     <asp:Textbox ID="txtDateViolated" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("date_violated")%>'></asp:Textbox>
                                <ajaxtoolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDateViolated">
                                </ajaxtoolkit:CalendarExtender>
                               </EditItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Case Status">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:Label ID="lblCaseStatus" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("case_status")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="dropCase" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("case_status")%>' >
                                        <asp:ListItem Value = "0">N.A.</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Value = "1">Pending</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Value = "2">Disposed</asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                               </EditItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                                                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" ShowHeader="false">
                                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnupdate" runat="server" CausesValidation="true"
                        Text="Update" onclick="btnupdate_Click" ></asp:LinkButton>
                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="CancelEdit" runat="server" CausesValidation="false"
                        Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                                            </EditItemTemplate>
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="EditViolation" runat="server" CausesValidation="false"
                        CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
                    <FooterStyle CssClass="gridviewfooter"/>
                <PagerStyle CssClass="gridviewfooter" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                <RowStyle CssClass="gridviewrow"/>
                <EmptyDataTemplate>There are no records to display.</EmptyDataTemplate>
                </asp:GridView>
                </div>
                </ContentTemplate> 
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                 </div>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PhilfishPhilcatchConnectionString %>">
                <InsertParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="v_id" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="violation" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="date_violated" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="case_status" />
                    </InsertParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and here is my code behind

```
Public Sub bindData()
        SqlDataSource2.InsertParameters.Item(0).DefaultValue = GridView1.SelectedDataKey.Value
        SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = "SELECT vessel_details.ship_name, vessel_details.registry_no, violation.violation, violation.date_violated, violation.case_status FROM vessel_details LEFT OUTER JOIN violation ON vessel_details.v_id = violation.v_id WHERE vessel_details.v_id ='" & GridView1.SelectedDataKey.Value & "'"
        SqlDataSource2.DataBind()
        GridView2.DataBind()
    End Sub
Protected Sub EditViolation(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewEditEventArgs)
        GridView2.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
        bindData()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub CancelEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCancelEditEventArgs)
        GridView2.EditIndex = -1
        bindData()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnupdate_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim txtViolation As TextBox = DirectCast(GridView2.FindControl("txtViolation"), TextBox)
        Dim txtDateViolated As TextBox = DirectCast(GridView2.FindControl("txtDateViolated"), TextBox)
        Dim dropCase As DropDownList = DirectCast(GridView2.FindControl("dropCase"), DropDownList)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
        cmd.CommandText = "Update violation set violation=@txtViolation, date_violated=@txtDateViolated, case_status=@dropCase where v_id = @v_id"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@v_id", GridView1.SelectedDataKey.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtViolation", txtViolation.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtDateViolated", txtDateViolated.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dropCase", dropCase.SelectedValue)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Parameters.Clear()
        bindData()
    End Sub
```

my update for gridview row is not working.
any suggestions? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have not associated your command with any connection object.
you need to associate connection object and need to open before cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(). As  below

```
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(SqlDataSource2.ConnectionString)
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = "Update violation set violation=@txtViolation, date_violated=@txtDateViolated, case_status=@dropCase where v_id = @v_id"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@v_id", GridView2.SelectedDataKey.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtViolation", txtViolation.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtDateViolated", txtDateViolated.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dropCase", dropCase.SelectedValue)
        Try
            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Parameters.Clear()
        Catch ex As Exception

        Finally
            con.Close()
            con.Dispose()
        End Try
```